# vs code не подсвечивает скрипты

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Мой vs code работает не корректно он не подсвечивает скрипты код как бы работает но он их не знает) следовательно в следующий раз он высвечивает их в строчном формате

[image: фото для просмотра]

у меня есть всего 2 расширения js(es6) & 'js -snippets' я их отключал и переустанавливал но не чего не помогло

Comment: Потому что е может быть чем угодно. Возможно вам стоит задуматься о jsDoc? С его помощью можно типизировать переменные и тогда vs должен показывать стандартные свойства и методы

Comment: А еще лучше использовать тайп скрипт!)